# Exclude the root from a ProxPass directive, but keep everything below the root included

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, mod-proxy, httpd.conf

I am running Apache in front of a Tomcat instance. Apache proxies every request that comes through and passes it on to Tomcat. The current configuration is such that Apache puts a `ProxyPass` on the root (/). There are however, new requirements, which specify that a call to the root of the domain should return a static splash page, and any other call should be proxied.

This means:

```
www.domain.com -> static page
www.domain.com/username - proxy to Tomcat
```

Making multiple ProxPass directives is not a good idea, because there are a lot of paths that must be supported by the Tomcat instance, and many of them change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirect any requests for plain www.domain.com to www.domain.com/index.html and then add an proxy exclude before forwarding everything else to Tomcat:

```
RewriteRule  ^/$                 /index.html
ProxyPass /index.html !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
<LocationMatch "/.+">
     # ProxyPass directives
</LocationMatch>
```